# Diff between DOS and MEV attacks

Tags: solidity

I have a query that can anyone explain main difference between DOS and MEV attack ? Because both leads to gas related issues.

Transaction reverts in the both cases which leads to an error.

So anyone clarify it ?

Comment: You can find [the explanation of MEV here](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/mev).